# Programming Menu for Game, Mouse detection method not working

Tags: java, slick2d

Here is the code for my method that is supposed to detect whether or not a mouse click is within a rectangle that I defined.

```
 private boolean mouseOver(int mx,int my,int x, int y, int width, int height){



    if((x < mx  && mx < x + width)&&(y < my && my < y + height)){
        System.out.print(mx+"\n"+my+"\n"+x+"\n"+y+"\n"+width+"\n"+height+"\n");
    return true;

    }else 
       System.out.print(mx+"\n"+my+"\n"+x+"\n"+y+"\n"+width+"\n"+height+"\n");
        return false;


}
```

This is where I am defining the rectangles (with text).

```
public void render(Graphics g){
    Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
    Font fnt1 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);
    g.setColor(Color.white);

    g.setFont(fnt);
    g.drawString("Menu", 240,70);
    g.setFont(fnt1);
    g.drawString("Play", 270,190);
    g.drawRect(210, 150, 200, 64);
    g.drawString("Scores", 270,290);
    g.drawRect(210, 250, 200, 64);
    g.drawString("Quit", 270,390);
    g.drawRect(210, 350, 200, 64);
}
```

Here is where the method is used.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    int mx = e.getY();
    int my = e.getX();
    //play button
    if (mouseOver(mx ,my ,210, 150, 200, 64)){
        game.gameState = STATE.Game;
    }
    //quit button
    if (mouseOver(mx ,my ,210, 350, 200, 64)){

        System.exit(1);

    }
}
```

When the method is called I commanded it to spit out the fields it takes, and here is an example.

mx = 185 my = 344 x = 210 y = 350 width = 200 height = 64
That data was from clicking the mouse inside of the rectangle, so it should have returned true if it was working properly.
Maybe it's returning the wrong coordinates of the mouse press?

Any ideas? 
I'm using a mac if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I was sending the x coordinate data to the y value in the equation and visa versa.

Answer (score 4):

One easy way to see where a Mouse Point is to use a Rectangle object and its `contains(Point p)` method.

For instance:

```
// constant section of your program
private static final STATE_RECTANGLE = new Rectangle(210, 150, 200, 64);
private static final QUIT_RECTANGLE = new Rectangle(210, 350, 200, 64);

// elsewhere
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    //play button
    if (STATE_RECTANGLE.contains(e.getPoint())) {
        game.gameState = STATE.Game;
    }
    //quit button
    if (QUIT_RECTANGLE.contains(e.getPoint())){
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

You can and should even use the same Rectangles to draw with after converting your Graphics object into a Graphics2D object by casting.

But having said this, we're only treating a symptom and not the disease as your program structure worries me. For one You've got way too many magic numbers, and that risks hard to debug errors. Also you're hard-coding your data which makes your program rigid and thus difficult to enhance and extend. Also you are mixing your view fully with your model, also making your code much more complex than it has to be and thus very difficult to debug, modify and enhance.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by "magic numbers"? I just started programming this year, in AP computer science

Comment: By constant section of program do you mean the super class?

Comment: Also when I create the rectangle constants netbeans asks me to create a Rectangle class, even with import java.awt.Rectangle;

Answer (score 3):

Your inequality operators are wrong.

```
(mx < x  && mx < x + width)&&(my < y && my < y + height)
```

Should be:

```
(x < mx  && mx < x + width)&&(y < my && my < y + height)
```

Before, you were just checking if the mouse's x and y position were lower than any point on the rectangle.

Comment: Is there anything else you see? It's still not working properly.

Comment: @JohnStivers how so? One thing I noticed is you draw the play button at `(210, 150, 200, 64)`, yet define the quit button at `(210, 150, 200, 64)`. Maybe you mixed the buttons up or something?

Comment: I did that trying to figure out why it wasnt working properly but i forgot to change it back when i pasted the code.. ill update that. When I click on the area where the button should be nothing happens, but there are two spaces in the window that seem random that play and quit the game.